# how to create auto table in spring dynamic web project

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring, hibernate

this is my code i created a dynamic web project in eclipse and write persistent class and below code. i created database also in mysql, but i am not getting this auto table creation. i got it in normal java project, but in dynamic web project am getting "The requested resource is not available." when i run Test.java, should i write anything in web.xml or index.jsp?

```
<hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">studb</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">12345</property>
     <property name="connection.pool_size"> 1</property> 

       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>


       <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
       <mapping resource="student.hbm.xml"/>

       </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

**student.hbm.xml**

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.javathub.Student" table="stu_details">
    <id name="id">
    <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="name"></property>
    <property name="branch"></property>
    <property name="fee"></property>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Univerysity</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` not `hbm2ddl.auto`. You can see the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional) for more information.